# Find programmatically using openssl which TLS version was negociated

Tags: c++, c, openssl

I'm using openssl in a non web application to commute a socket to TLS (STARTTLS protocol). Everything works fine, but I would also like to know which version of TLS among the allowed ones was actually negociated.

Is there any way to find this information using openssl API ?

Note: with openssl 1.1 and later the information is likely returned by the function [SSL_SESSION_get_protocol_version()](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_SESSION_get_protocol_version.html) but I need to also find this information for previous openssl library versions (code in the wild, performing a major update of openssl for mere logging purpose is not an option).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`SSL_get_version()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/ssl/SSL_get_version.html):

> SSL_get_version() returns the name of the protocol used for the connection `ssl`. It should only be called after the initial handshake has been completed. Prior to that the results returned from this function may be unreliable.
>
> RETURN VALUES
>
> The following strings can be returned:
>
> SSLv2
> The connection uses the SSLv2 protocol.
>
> SSLv3
> The connection uses the SSLv3 protocol.
>
> TLSv1
> The connection uses the TLSv1.0 protocol.
>
> TLSv1.1
> The connection uses the TLSv1.1 protocol.
>
> TLSv1.2
> The connection uses the TLSv1.2 protocol.
>
> unknown
> This indicates an unknown protocol version.